# FATAL: could not connect to the primary server: expected authentication request from server, but received S

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to crate master slave replication scenario in Postgress server.
I  have create a master with the 5300 port and slave have the 5500
here is my postgresql.conf.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port              = 5300
wal_level         = hot_standby
max_wal_senders   = 3
wal_keep_segments = 8
synchronous_standby_names = 'slave1'
```

I have created pg_hba.conf with following configurations.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                        trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all                127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all                ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                        trust
host    replication     all                127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all                ::1/128                 trust
host    replication     <database-user>    127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     <database-user>    172.16.217.185/32       md5
host    replication     <database-user>    172.16.217.187/32       md5
```

Then I create cluster with the following command.

```
initdb
```

and then I start my master cluster with the following command.

```
bin/pg_ctl -w -l master/logs -o "-p 5300" start
```

and that command is running fine.
then I create the slave folder and copy all the master data in to it.
and past this folder to the slave side.
then after configuration I did create recovary.conf.

and put the following in it.

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo ='host=172.16.217.185 port=5300 user=<db_user> password=<Password> application_name=slave1'
```

then I start my slave.

```
pg_ctl -w -l slave/logs -o "-p 5500" start
```

that give me error when i see the slave/logs.
I see the error i have shared above.

> FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: expected
>   authentication request from server, but received S
>   and remember I am running all the scenario in the VMFusion.

and one more thing  I have try this with firewall enable/disable/allow 
all them gives me the same so its not firewall that causing this error.

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Actually this error occurs when more then one clusters are working on the same machine and when you run the following command.

```
pg_ctl -w -l slave/logs -o "-p 5500" start
```

The server got confused that which cluster should respond.
I resolve this issue while stopping all the clusters and starting the the concern one.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have an archive named recovery.conf in your /data Slave directory, the file needs to content:

`standby_mode = 'on'`

`primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.x.x port=5432 user=rep password=xxxxxx'`

`trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'`

where 192.168.x.x you need to change with your Master Ip
and of course password is about user rep